# Remove duplicate words and just print lines in which this occurs

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a challenge to look in a file if a sentence contains 2 identical consecutive words. If so, you print the word; otherwise, you don't print the sentence.

Example:

```
abc2 1 def2 3 abc2
F4
--------------
dea 123 123 zy45
12 12
abc cd abc cd
xyz%$@! xyz%$@! kk
xyzxyz
abc h h h h
```

After running the program the output will be:

```
dea 123 zy45
12
xyz%$@! kk
abc h h h
3
```

This is what I have so far:

```
sed '/\([^\([^ ]\+\)[ ]\+\1]\)/d' F4 >|tmp
```

I got this so far but this is only separating between the sentences that have the double word and sentences that don't.

Comment: In order to rewrite the line to get rid of one of the duplicate words, you need to use a `s///` command, not `d`.

Comment: You seem to have an extra `[` and `]` in your command, so I don't see how it does what you say it does.

Comment: Where is coming from the 3 in the bottom of the expected output?

Comment: You write `If so, you print the word;`. The subject and output is different, delete that word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sed` expression was quite accurate. However, it needed some mangling to make it work:

```
$ sed -nr 's/\b(\S+)\s+\1(\s|$)/\1/p' file
dea 123 zy45
12
xyz%$@! kk
abc h h h
```

The idea is the one  you already implemented: match a given word with `[^ ]` and see if you match it again with `\1`. What I added is all of this to be replaced with `\1` so the repeated block disappears.

Instead of `[^ ]` it is also useful to use `\S` and instead of `[ ]`, `\s`. Note also the usage of `\b` as a word boundary to prevent false positives like `fedorqui qui` and the usage of `\1(\s|$)` to prevent other false positives like `hello helloa` (thanks [WalterA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3220113/walter-a) for the examples!). Note the usage of `\s|$` to match either a space or the end of the line; `\b` matches any not-word character, which makes it not useful for the case with `xyz%$@! kk`.

To prevent all lines to be printed, we use `sed -n`. This way, we just print (with `p`) those that go through the regular expression that was defined.

Note the usage of `-r` to get rid of all those escaping to capture groups. Without it, the command would be:

```
sed -n 's/\b\([^ ]\+\)[ ]\+\1/\1/p' file
```

---

Let's test it with a more comprehensive input:

```
$ cat a
abc2 1 def2 3 abc2
F4
--------------
dea 123 123 zy45
12 12
abc cd abc cd
xyz%$@! xyz%$@! kk
xyzxyz
fedorqui qui
hello helloa
abc h h h h
$ sed -nr 's/\b(\S+)\s+\1(\s|$)/\1/p' a
dea 123zy45
12
xyz%$@!kk
abc hh h
```

Comment: You are matching a substring like `fedorqui qui`.

Comment: @WalterA very good point! Added a word boundary to prevent so. Thanks.

Comment: Your change with `\b` also fixed `abc cd abc cd` that was truncated into `abcd abc cd`. But how about the second string as a substring of the first like `walter waltera` ?

Comment: @WalterA and this was another good point that needed bigger weapons to address.

Comment: And how about `%$@!xyz %$@!xyz kk`? You explained that `\b` won't work at the end of the line, so it will cause problems too at the start of a word.

Comment: @WalterA I will go through this tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a `sed` solution that seemed to be easy. perhaps in this case `awk` is better (`F4` is the inputfile):

```
awk '{
        for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) { 
           if ($(i-1)==$i) { 
              $i="";
              printf("%s\n", $0);
              break;
           }
        }
     }' F4
```

I am not complete happy with this solution, since it will leave a double FieldSep in `$0` after deleting the doubled word, but literally the OP did not see that a space or tab should be deleted too.